# Kotlin: Unresolved reference: Textview

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and android in general.

Currently making an app that is supposed to calculate a persons age in minutes, however Im getting an  error saying "Unresolved reference: TextView". The thing is, as you can see, I've already imported widget.Textview.

Please help... I'm stuck on such a trivial problem. Thank you.

P.S. There have been similar questions, but the solutions either aren't applicable or have already been applied.

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var tvSelectedDate : Textview? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btndate : Button = findViewById(R.id.btndate)
        tvSelectedDate = findViewById(R.id.tvSelectedDate)
        btndate.setOnClickListener {
            clickDatePicker()
        }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a simple typo:

> ```
> private var tvSelectedDate : Textview? = null
> ```

You have written `Textview`, but should have written `TextView` (with a captial "V").

Answer (score -1):

Simply using databinding to get view id and handle alot of issues

1. [Data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding)